# How To Disable Vibrancy Continued Theme in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was exploring some of VS Code's themes and came across one called Vibrancy Continued. I ended up not liking the effect it gives to the interphase and wanted to disable it and uninstall. However when I tried this nothing happened. The theme still remained. How can I get rid of the effect when disabling and uninstalling the theme both do not work?

1. I tried uninstalling the theme then restarting VS Code
2. I also tried uninstalling all other themes and reverting back to VS Code's default theme
3. Tried installing and enabling an entirely new theme and that did not work either

Comment: You can use `ctrl+k` followed by `ctrl+t` to bring up the theme browser. Or click on the `settings` gear icon, then select `Themes > Color Theme`. At any rate, disabling or uninstalling the theme extension should have caused your VS Code to revert to the default theme.

Comment: I also would consider reinstalling vscode. that theme modifies the core css of the editor

Answer (score 1):

To disable Vibracy Continued:

Press F1 or ⌘+Shift+P and activate command "Disable Vibrancy" (not on the extensions page, that doesn`t work), then restart Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by reinstalling the theme and doing the step "Disable Vibrancy" as described in te FAQ of the theme, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=illixion.vscode-vibrancy-continued#FAQs

If that did not help, your VS Code setup is most likely so messed up that it'd be better to reinstall VS Code, since the theme modifies the core CSS of VS Code.  Remember to back up any config files, such as your user settings JSON file, workspace settings JSON files and keybindings JSON file.

Edit: Or you can turn on the settings sync in VS Code, which will backup everything for you: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync

Edit2: The user config isn't deleted when reinstalling. as https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/uninstall#_clean-uninstall says, you need to delete it manually if you wanted to get rid of it.

Comment: Thank You. Turning on sync then reinstalling VS Code worked.

Comment: That's nice to hear! If you think that this question is resolved, consider giving it an upvote and accepting it.

Comment: uninstallation does not remove user config files

Comment: That's a good catch, didn't realize that the user config has to be deleted manually if one wants to get rid of it @starball